# How do I avoid "already used by another worker" warning in an Apache2 reverse proxy config?

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, configuration

I added server matching ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse entries, but I was getting "already used by another worker" [warn] messages upon start up.

I have a proposed solution that's good enough for me, since it appears to have cleared up the messages and pretty much made me forget about this problem. This solution is to put the entries in reverse-case order in the config file.

I think the real issue had to do with expression matching, since if "Videos" was listed before "Videos2", there was a warning. Once I reversed these entries, the warnings stopped.

Answer (score 7):

I realize this is an old post, but since it came up in a google search I was doing I figured I'd post some helpful information I found regarding this same error.

In some cases this error message is benign. For example, I was getting it in CentOS 5 but by proxy config was perfectly legitimate and worked just fine. You can view the discussion regarding this issue here:
https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44350

and note that the suggestion to move this to a "debug" level error instead of a "warn" level error has been implemented in newer versions of mod_proxy:
https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48947

Hope this helps anyone also searching for this error on the internet!

Answer (score 6):

As you discovered, you need to specify the more specific matches first.

Answer (score 2):

According to Apache's bugzilla this should be fixed in 2.2.16, see https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48947